# WildFly 8.1 restarts after every change after upgrade to Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, wildfly, jboss-tools

I'm currently working on a Java EE 7 project using:

- Eclipse Luna 4.4
- JBOSS Tools 4.2.0 beta 2
- WildFly 8.1.0 Final
- MyFaces 2.2.4

After upgrade from Kepler, my servers started misbehaving - after every small change in XHTML server restarts. In server overview I've set Publishing -> Automatically publish when resources change, like it was before. Also checked both options in Deployment scanners. I have not change anything in my standalone.xml since the upgrade to Luna. Restarts happen even if I do not use Eclipse and only start the server from command line. Has anyone an idea how to change server's behaviour to NOT restart every time but merely do a HOT-swap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in JBoss Tools 4.2.0 Beta3. It should be released relatively soon. You're welcome to try a nightly build.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-17724