# JBoss re-deploys on every file change after upgrading to Eclipse Luna

Tags: deployment, jboss7.x, publish, eclipse-luna

After upgrading my Eclipse installation to Luna (from Kepler), my JBoss servers started being overly pedantic with the redeployment of my web projects: even if I change a JavaScript file, a deployment replacement begins and takes significant amount of time. The same happens for JSP files too.

I've set **Publishing** to *Automatically publish when resources change* (as it was in Kepler), I've deleted/added JBoss 7.0 several times, tried various combinations of the checkboxes in **Deployment Scanners** & **Application Reload Behavior**, the issue persists though.

Configuration:

- Eclipse Luna 4.4
- JBoss Tools 4.2 beta 2
- JBoss server 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching further, I found that this was a bug in the beta 2 version of JBoss Tools 4.2 for Luna.

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910771/wildfly-8-1-restarts-after-every-change-after-upgrade-to-eclipse-luna), `beta 3` of JBoss Tools fixes this issue.